# How can I go to specific url from template in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have bunch of urls in urls.py , and In template I have defined like below :

```
  <li><a href="{% url 'vieweinvoices' %}">Billing</a></li>  
  <li><a href="{% url 'proformainvoice' %}">Proforma Invoice</a></li>  
  <li><a href="{% url 'viewequotations' %}">Quotation</a></li>
```

But the problem is if I click on one line say viewinvoices, and after that I click on proformainvoice, it redirects to 
`localhost:8000/vieweinvoices/proformainvoice.html` but it should go to `localhost:8000/proformainvoice.html` how can I do that?

views.py :

```
def vieweinvoices(request):
    alltaxInvoice = taxInvoice.objects.all()
    totalInvoices = taxInvoice.objects.all().count()
    startdate = datetime.today()
    enddate = startdate - timedelta(days=14)
    totalthismonthsInvoices = taxInvoice.objects.filter(
        invoicedate__range=[startdate, enddate]
    ).count()
    context = {
        "alltaxInvoice": alltaxInvoice,
        "totalInvoices": totalInvoices,
        "totalthismonthsInvoices": totalthismonthsInvoices,
        "startdate": startdate,
        "enddate": enddate,
    }
    return render(request, "Invoice/TaxInvoice/viewinvoice.html", context)
```

all views are like this
and 
urls.py

```
 path("vieweinvoices/", views.vieweinvoices, name="vieweinvoices"),
    path("viewequotations/", views.viewequotations, name="viewequotations"),
```

Comment: I think the problem is not in templates. Show your views and urls files.

Comment: Could you please add the `proformainvoice` path from your `urls.py` also?

Comment: `path("proformainvoice/", views.proformainvoice, name="proformainvoice"),`

Comment: Can you share the urls from the project's `urls.py`. I believe above urls are from the app's `urls.py`